# FFmpeg: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound on RMTP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I want to take snapshots periodically of a RTMP live video stream.
I can see the rtmp video stream using VLC. This is the rtmp url:

```
rtmp://antena3fms35livefs.fplive.net/antena3fms35live-live/stream-antena3_1
```

I'm using the following command to capture the snapshots, according to the official FFmpeg site [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video):

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://antena3fms35livefs.fplive.net/antena3fms35live-live/stream-antena3_1 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 out%d.png
```

The command produces the following output:

```
ffmpeg version N-64667-gd595361 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 14 2014 22:09:48 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzl
libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amr
enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
HandShake: client signature does not match!
Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
rtmp://antena3fms35livefs.fplive.net/antena3fms35live-live/stream-antena3_1: Unknown error occurred
```

I've tried it with another rmtp streams, but I'm still getting the exact same error.

What could be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: This error could mean that ffmpeg didn't manage to "guess" correctly how to parse the url. Same error shows in rtmpdump and is fixed by writing the url explicitly via the -y flag. ffmpeg also suppose to have a similar feature (the [rtmp_playpath parameter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html)) for passing correct value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just tried your command and it worked fine for me.  Maybe it is something about your FFMPEG installation?  I am using version 2.4 on a Mac (tessus build).

I know other/older versions used "librtmp" for rtmp connections, which required some extra options behind the stream URL.  See ffmpeg docs here:
[ffmpeg documentation on librtmp](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#librtmp-rtmp_002c-rtmpe_002c-rtmps_002c-rtmpt_002c-rtmpte)

And librtmp docs here:
[librtmp documentation](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html)

For an unprotected live stream, you may want to try quoting the stream URL and appending " live=1" within the quotes:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://antena3fms35livefs.fplive.net/antena3fms35live-live/stream-antena3_1 live=1" -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 out%d.png
```

Comment: Thank you! That "live=1" parameter solved my problem!

Comment: I'm using 2.8.6 on both mac and linux(ubuntu). The mac works fine w/o `live=1` but ubuntu requires it. Any idea what the difference is?

Comment: Awesome, also helped on linux with version `2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`.