# Fail to restream with nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I'm unable to start restream using command `exec`. Also I tried `exec_pull`.
It didn't help. My target is to restream `rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream` url to my local nginx, to `rtmp://localhost:1935/hls`.
`/tmp/logs/ffmpeg.log` is empty. 
I guess that `exec` not even called, but why?

```
    rtmp {

    server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4096;

    application live {
        allow play all;
        live on;
        record off;
        #pull rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream;
        exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls 2>>/tmp/logs/ffmpeg.log;
    }

        application hls {
        allow play all;
        live on;
        record off;
    }

    }
```

I'm using nginx-1.12.0.
I followed by [this tutorial](https://helping-squad.com/transcoding-your-video-with-nginx/), watched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625257/re-stream-other-stream-with-niginx-software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, *first* of all, be aware of that Nginx run all your exec commands as `nobody` user. And you have to test it in command line like this:

```
sudo -u nobody ffmpeg -i rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls
```

And then if this command line works - print to nginx.conf.

*Secondly*, use the full path. It's **very important**, because a child process than Nginx runs has different environment compared with your current user environment.

```
sudo -u nobody /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls
```

*Thirdly*, my mistake was that I used FFmpeg from the repository and that FFmpeg has `2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` version. Related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890111/4372276)
FFmpeg can be compiled with [librtmp](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html), that's why FFmpeg can require live=1 and quotes(**"**). So the final command that I copied to nginx.conf was:

```
sudo -u nobody /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream live=1" -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls
```

---

My final nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
 server {
      listen 1935;
      chunk_size 4096;

       application live {
           live on;
           record off;
           pull rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream;
           exec_play /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "rtmp://ktv.s4c.link/live/livestream live=1" -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls 2>>/tmp/ffmpeg-$name.log;
       }

       application hls {
           live on;
           record off;
       }

  }
```

As you can mention I added FFmpeg logs `2>>/tmp/ffmpeg-$name.log`.